# Is that possible to move whole block of data in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Im trying to make a code to draw that square faster, and I'm wondering if it is possible to put it in memory somehow and when i need to move it just take it from memory with other starting coords?

(how the whole program works: when you press arrows on keyboard the square will move to one of the sides of the screen)

```
    mov coords, 20*320+100      ;20 line , 100 column
    mov ah, 0                   ; graphic mode set
    mov al, 13h                 ; 13h = 320x200, 256 colors.
    int 10h     


        ;/////// Drawing a Square ////////
    mov ax, 0a000h      
    mov es, ax
    mov di,coords
    loop:
    mov al, 15      ;color, 15 - white
    mov cx, 13      ;13 pixels in a row
    rep stosw       ;loop  
    inc counter
    add di,320-26       ;set pointer to lower line same column as before
    cmp counter,25
    JNE loop
```

Comment: It won't be faster than drawing it. You can optimize your draw code somewhat though.

Comment: You can exploit the palette to draw a frame and then change the colour of same part of it. For example, draw both rectangles and change the palette to show only one at a time.

Comment: That trick with palette will not work becouse i need more than 2 positions of that square. 

So optimizating this code is impossible?

Comment: On an 8086, `rep movsw` or `rep stosw` are about the fastest ways to move data around. On modern processors, there are faster ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the important part of answer:

Your current solution is quite close to optimal, `stosw` into VRAM is faster than copy (`movsw`) RAM->VRAM, and lot more faster than VRAM->VRAM copy (`movsw` from old position in video memory to new position + plus it would need to recognize overlapping areas and resolve it by correct cld/std direction of transfer ... anyway, avoid *reading* video ram whenever possible).

That said, if you would do many small-ish rectangles per frame and/or rectangles with considerable overdraw, after certain threshold it may be better to draw into RAM 320x200 buffer first, and then copy whole buffer into VRAM in single go. This would also solve any blinking/flickering due to visible artefacts from overlapping/overdrawing, when you are not fast enough to update VRAM data ahead of CRT beam (virtual on LCD, but still works like that, scanning row by row in 60Hz-per-screen (or what refresh rate your gfx card+lcd supports)).

Also there are few details, but first of all, why 8086? It doesn't make much sense, dosbox can easily emulate 386. Are you running really at original PC XT or AT machine with 8086 only? If you are running in emu8086, I don't think that's performance oriented emulator, it's more like schooling tool, so again switching to dosbox would probably give you better speeds even with current code, plus it would allow you to use 32b extensions of 80386+.

About the details of code:

```
    ; set es + di first of course, this starts where "loop:" was.
; ???  mov al, 15      ;color, 15 - white
    mov ax,0A0Fh    ; stosw does store "ax", not "al"
    ; so your code from question does store 0A0F values, not 0F0F. Was it typo?
    ; anyway, moved outside of loop
    mov dx,25       ; row counter
    ; ^ do NOT use memory when you have spare register available!
align 4
row_loop:           ; avoid labels equal to x86 instructions, like "loop"
    mov cx, 13      ; 26 pixels in row
    dec dx
    rep stosw       ; set pixels
    lea di,[di+320-26] ; address of next line start
    jnz row_loop
```

This should be tiny bit faster (like ~1%).

On 80386 you can do `rep stosd`, which will be considerably faster than `stosw`, especially if you will align it to div 4 address in `edi` ... maybe even 10-30% faster.

---

If you would have only single rectangle on screen, or everything would move at the same speed/direction, you can use VGA "X-modes" to set "scroll" the whole image by setting new start of screen in VGA, drawing the pixels only once. But that's so special case, even more special than the palette trick, that I'm mentioning it just for completeness, I don't believe this would suffice for you.

Comment: Thanks for help, to answer your question "why 8086?" it's like you said for school purposes :) I have a little abitious teacher so we are doing things like that. 

Can you tell me why did you put "align 4" before row_loop ?
Another question: why when in cx is 13 its 26 pixels in a row? Shouldn't be 13?

Comment: "align 4" will add necessary amount of `NOP` (or NOP-ish) instructions ahead of `mov cx,13`, so the `mov` will be at address divisible by 4. 8086 would probably not care at all, but modern generations of x86 love this, usually with modern x86 it's worth to align labels to 8 byte boundaries, if you jump at them a lot (like loop labels or important function entry points). It's making it easier for CPU to fetch the opcodes from memory, as modern x86 does fetch bytes in chunks of at least 4 or more.

Comment: @Szprota21 About pixels: **you** did use `stosw`. That stores `ax` at `[es:di], di+=2`. But 13h mode is using 1 byte per 1 pixel. If you store two bytes with single write, you are drawing two pixels at the same time (it's faster this way). You also do `add di,320-26`, so it did look like you fully understand what you did. Then again from the `mov al,15` maybe you didn't? I wonder why you didn't notice only every second pixel is white, and the other ones were some weird (dark?) color `0A0h` (in my answer I have wrong `0A` for `ah`, but it is `A0` actually).

Comment: If you want only 13 pixels, then do `ax = color:color, cx=6, rep stosw, stosb`. In 32b mode it would be better to do `eax=color:color:color:color, stosd stosd stosd stosb` (writing 3* 4B (four pixels at the same time) and then final 13th pixel alone).

Comment: About teaching 8086 .. usually I'm in favour of teaching the old CPU assembly, because modern x86 is beast full of hidden complexities, you can hardly say any simple sentence about it, like for example "`al` is lower 8 bits of `eax`" -> bang, landed on mine, modern x86 is internally using hundreds of registers dynamically renaming/aliasing them to the "front-end" `eax, ebx, ecx, ...`  So that `al` is in reality different register, and using `eax` immediately after write into `al` will cause performance penalty, as the CPU will have to merge two regs (old `eax` with upper 24b + new 8b).

Comment: But 8086 is maybe a bit too much... actually 80386 in flat mapped protected mode is still "naively" done on HW side, but much easier to explain + learn (no segments, less limited address modes, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answers and opinion. I will definitely try 80386 when i will done that program. Thanks a lot