# Scrolling the terminal sideways (BIOS)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, bios

I am writing a bootsector game which attempts to copy the chrome dinosaur game you can play when you have no internet.

To do this, I must run from left to right until the player hits a cactus.

How do I achieve this?
(How do I make the terminal scroll from right to left so that it looks like I am moving?)
So instead of scrolling up and down, I need to scroll from right to left and left to right.
I am in 16 bit real mode (BIOS), and I am using nasm / intel syntax.

Comment: is there a stackoverflow question here?   Please ask it.

Comment: Yes, read the question.
I asked how to make the BIOS scroll from left to right

Comment: I don't think there's a BIOS call for this.  You can however implement the scroll logic yourself.

Comment: @fuz But how can I go about doing this? (I am still learning assembly)

Comment: @acoder Which video mode are you in?  I can write a detailed answer if this is helpful to you.

Comment: @fuz I will be using two modes. Later on I will make the game in video mode, but for now, I am in text mode (80 x 25, 16 colors)

Comment: @acoder That's unfortunate as the method will differ between text and video modes (and different video modes require different methods, too).

Comment: @fuz It is currently enough for me if I can get text mode scrolling working.
(I am developing a kind of emulator which has a selection of games a player can choose from. Some use video, some use text)

Comment: @acoder Fair enough.  I will then prepare an answer about that.

Comment: @acoder and you looked up your video card and the register settings in it?  And have a question about those?

Comment: I didnt see your code nor register names.

Comment: you are stil asking us to look stuff up for you which is not a stackoverflow question

Comment: intel syntax or programming language in general is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: There is no code to be shown. I am asking for an implementation of this scrolling.

I can scroll the BIOS terminal regardless of my video card.
I am ONLY asking how I can scroll the BIOS terminal left or right.

This is not a question of what card, but of how this is implemented.

Comment: @fuz was just confirming that the question is about seeking recommendations which it is...

Comment: @old_timer The question is not about software or tool recommendations.  It is a clear algorithms question and is on topic.  Please cut it out.

Comment: I second that this question is on-topic, because it is perfectly answerable for BIOS text mode _and_ BIOS graphics mode.

Comment: @old_timer: The legacy BIOS boot environment emulates legacy hardware including VGA to present an IBM PC-compatible environment.  This wouldn't be answerable for an ARM board for example without knowing the specific graphics hardware, but it is answerable given the tags `[bios]`, `[bootloader]`, and `[nasm]` (an assembler that can only target x86).  This implies x86 legacy BIOS booting with an MBR boot sector, with VGA graphics "hardware". As fuz said, cut it out.  I'm not interested in the question, but there's no need to nit-pick it to death. It's just barely specific enough, given text-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CGA-compatible text modes, the screen contents are stored in a 4000 byte buffer starting at `B800:000` (unless you change the active display page, but I'll just assume you don't).  Each line contains 80 characters and is stored in 160 bytes with 25 lines in total for a resolution of 80×25.

So to scroll the screen left, you have to move the characters of the screen left by the desired number of columns and fill the right hand side of the screen with blank characters.  This can be achieved easily using a series of `rep movsw` instructions to move the characters followed by `rep stosw` instructions to fill the right hand side.  Assuming `ds = es = b800` and assuming `ds:di` points to the beginning of the line, the code for shifting a single line left by `c` columns looks like this:

```
        lea     si, [di+2*c]   ; set up SI to the column that is scrolled
                               ; into the first column of the line
        mov     cx, 80-c       ; copy all columns beginning at that column
                               ; to the end of the row
        rep     movsw          ; scroll row to the left
        mov     cx, c          ; need to blank that many columns
        rep     stosw          ; blank remaining columns
```

After this code sequence, `DI` points to the beginning of the next row.  So by iterating this sequence 25 times, we can easily scroll the entire screen:

```
        mov     ax, 0xb800     ; screen segment
        mov     ds, ax         ; set up segments
        mov     es, ax
        xor     di, di         ; point to the beginning of the screen
        mov     dx, 25         ; process 25 lines
        mov     ax, 0x0700     ; what to scroll in (grey on black blanks)

.loop:  lea     si, [di+2*c]   ; set up SI to the column that is scrolled
                               ; into the first column of the line
        mov     cx, 80-c       ; copy all columns beginning at that column
                               ; to the end of the row
        rep     movsw          ; scroll row to the left
        mov     cx, c          ; need to blank that many columns
        rep     stosw          ; blank remaining columns

        dec     dx             ; decrement loop counter
        jnz     .loop          ; loop until we're done
```

And that's really all there is to it.  Of course, if `c` is variable instead of a constant, the code becomes slightly more complicated.  But I'm confident you'll figure it out.

Also note that you seem to refer to the screen as the “BIOS terminal” or something like this.  That's not correct.  The screen is drawn by the graphics card and can in fact by changed entirely without the BIOS.  The BIOS is a set of routines provided in a ROM on your computer.  These include some routines to configure graphics modes and to print characters and so on.  However, that's purely for convenience.  You don't actually need to go through the BIOS to do any of this.

Comment: For performance, it *might* be more efficient to do one large `rep movsw`, then stride down the columns writing the last word.  (If scrolling by only 1 or 2 characters).  That avoids startup overhead for fast-strings microcode on every row.  But on WC video memory, it might only be copying 1 word at a time (because reads aren't cacheable), not using wide loads and stores, so redundant copying might be bad.  If you do this during vertical-blanking, the temporary garbage (first column copied to end of previous line) won't be visible...

Comment: [Is that possible to move whole block of data in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41598941) points out that VRAM->VRAM copying is much slower than just writing vram.  So probably if performance mattered, updating a shadow copy of VRAM and then mirroring it the VGA memory with one `rep movsw` would be idea on a modern PC, where VGA text RAM fits in L1d cache which is so much faster than an uncached 16-bit read of video RAM.  `rep movsw` from WB memory *to* video RAM should be able to do wide stores, taking advantage of write-combining since we don't read WC memory.